# SimpleDateFormat throws exception

Tags: java

I want to show a date string in this format: `Jun 27, 2012`. I did this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyy");
String date = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance());
```

But it gives me this:

> `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which exception is it throwing and what does its message say?

Comment: try Calendar.getInstance().getTime()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not use `Calendar.getInstance()`, since the param for same is date and not calender instance. Just change the param to `getTime()`

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
String date = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 10):

```
sdf.format()
```

Takes a `Date`, not a `Calendar` object.

Comment: +1 Which is why it gives `IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date`

Comment: Anyway, the output is "jun 27, 2012" instead of "Jun 27, 2012". Is there a way to capitalize the first letter by means of the date formatter?

Comment: @santirivera92: What locale are you using, and what do you *want* to use? For example, what would you expect for April? (My guess is that at the moment you'll get "avr" for "Avril".)

Comment: I have not declared any locale, but in my locale I'd get "abr" for "Abril", I'm from Spain